# Implementing a 7x7 grid programmatically using UICollectionView

Tags: cocoa-touch, grid, uicollectionview

How would you implement a 7x7 grid using UICollectionView? This grid would have no spaces in between each cell and also when it rotates the cells would simply resize to fit the screen, so it will always be 7x7 no matter what.

I have the following classes already done, a ViewController, a Cell class, a CollectionViewLayout class.

My original thinking was that I would have to do this in the CollectionViewLayout class, but which methods should I target to do this?

Comment: `– collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `– numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:`. Disclaimer: I've never used `UICollectionView`, I've just looked up this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adjusting the datasource methods to return 7 sections and 7 rows per section, you have to have your view controller comply to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

Assuming you want no spaces (having set the minimum spacing to 0) you can then use this method to size the cell:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width/7.0,
                    self.collectionView.bounds.size.height/7.0);
}
```

Actually, to make this work, you need another 2 tweaks. First, you should react to interface orientations, like this:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
     (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

  [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Second, to ensure one section does not get broken into 2 lines, you might have to use `7.01` for the division rather than `7.0`.